# Change mode and owner for mounted SD card

Tags: permissions, sd-card, mountpoint, ownership

*[Ubuntu 14.04.5 64bits]*

I mount an SD card with `rw` permission, on `/mnt/XYZ` using a udev rule that also triggers a script using it as storage. If the SD card is not mounted, the script is inhibited.

Everything works well, except I'd like:

- the card and its content to be owned not by `root:root` as is the case now, but by `root:admin`, (`admin` is a user group I create for certain admin tasks)
- them to have ugo `rwx` permissions of type 640,
- any folder created on the SD card to have the `setgid` bit.

When the SD is not mounted I can do as I please with the mount point: /mnt/XYZ has permissions `drwxr-s---`, and `root:admin` ownership, just as I want. As soon as I mount the SD card, things change:

- the mount point becomes `root:root` and I cannot change it,
- the content is also `root:root` and I cannot change it,
- I cannot change content files' permissions either, as exemplified by :
  `chown: changing ownership of ‘local.key’: Operation not permitted`

Could it have something to do with format (MBR/FAT32) not allowing unix like permission attributes. Reformatting the SD card as NTFS does not help. I have not tries ext4.  I have no  trouble at all with managing permissions and/or attributes for files on ext4 SSD paritions mounted from `fstab` for instance.

**Q:** *Is ext4 the only solution in this case ?*

Comment: ^same issue and solution for FAT32 (except for the POSIX permission support of NTFS). I doubt you can get setgid to work on FAT32, not that it will matter, since everything will have the ownership and mode set by the mount options. Best use ext4 if you need more fine-grained permission controls.

Comment: Yes, thanks @muru solution is either `ntfs-3g.usermap` (per your referenced link in 1st comment) or `ext4`. 
Mods: Sorry about the dupe.  Should I just delete the question ?

Comment: Keep the question, mark as a duplicate (useful for searching)